# Обновление таблицы ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

Есть такой вывод данных с базы

```
initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                hideCollapseTool: true,
                columnLines: true,
                viewConfig: {
                    stripeRows: true
                },
                tbar: [{
                    scope: this,
                    handler: this.onAddClick,
                    tooltip: 'Обновить',
                    tooltipType: 'title',
                    iconCls:'refresh-icon'
                },
                {
                    scope: this,
                    iconCls:'download-icon',
                    disabled: true,
                    tooltip: 'Загрузить',
                    tooltipType: 'title',
                    handler: this.onAddClick
                }],
                store: 'TelCatalogStore',
                columns: [{
                    text     : 'Имя',
                    flex     : 1,
                    sortable : true,
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                },
                {
                    text     : 'Тип',
                    sortable : false,
                    dataIndex: 'type'
                },
                {
                    text     : 'Дата',
                    sortable : false,
                    dataIndex: 'data'
                },
                {
                    text     : 'Статус',
                    width    : 75,
                    sortable : false,
                    renderer : this.changeRenderer,
                    dataIndex: 'status'
                }]
            }]
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
```

Я добавил сюда такую кнопку

```
tbar: [{
                    scope: this,
                    handler: this.onAddClick,
                    tooltip: 'Обновить',
                    tooltipType: 'title',
                    iconCls:'refresh-icon'
                }
```

Как написать функцию что бы когда нажимаешь на кнопку таблица обновлялась?

Comment: За что минус то а?

Comment: Я полагаю, что минус за "напишите за меня". SO сделан не для этого. Для подобных просьб надо идти на тематические форумы, в данном случае на форум sencha.

Comment: Спасибо буду знать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.getViewName.getStore.load();
```

обновляет store

Answer (score 0):

```
onAddClick: function(me) {
 this.down('grid').getStore().load();
}
```